# Buddhism and Astral Projection

Tags: meditation, sleep

I was wondering if anyone had any insight into the possibility of there being “Astral Projection” in Buddhism. I know “Tibetan Sleep Yoga” is involved with Lucid Dreaming, which is the internal. Yet I was wondering if Buddhism had a concept where you could leave your body.

Any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 4):

If you mean by this definition:

> Astral projection (or astral travel), is a term used in esotericism to
> describe an intentional out-of-body experience (OBE) that assumes the
> existence of a soul called an "astral body" that is separate from the
> physical body and capable of travelling outside it throughout the
> universe

Then there are only a few verses that can be *interpreted* as such in the Pali Canon, for example in the [Samaññaphala Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.02.0.than.html) of the [Digha Nikaya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C4%ABgha_Nik%C4%81ya):

> "With his mind thus concentrated, purified, and bright, unblemished,
> free from defects, pliant, malleable, steady, and attained to
> imperturbability, he directs and inclines it to creating a mind-made
> body. From this body he creates another body, endowed with form, made
> of the mind, complete in all its parts, not inferior in its faculties.
> Just as if a man were to draw a reed from its sheath. The thought
> would occur to him: 'This is the sheath, this is the reed. The sheath
> is one thing, the reed another, but the reed has been drawn out from
> the sheath.' Or as if a man were to draw a sword from its scabbard.
> The thought would occur to him: 'This is the sword, this is the
> scabbard. The sword is one thing, the scabbard another, but the sword
> has been drawn out from the scabbard.' Or as if a man were to pull a
> snake out from its slough. The thought would occur to him: 'This is
> the snake, this is the slough. The snake is one thing, the slough
> another, but the snake has been pulled out from the slough.' In the
> same way — with his mind thus concentrated, purified, and bright,
> unblemished, free from defects, pliant, malleable, steady, and
> attained to imperturbability, the monk directs and inclines it to
> creating a mind-made body. From this body he creates another body,
> endowed with form, made of the mind, complete in all its parts, not
> inferior in its faculties.
>
> ...
>
> With his mind thus concentrated, purified, and bright, unblemished,
> free from defects, pliant, malleable, steady, and attained to
> imperturbability, he directs and inclines it to the modes of
> supranormal powers. He wields manifold supranormal powers. Having been
> one he becomes many; having been many he becomes one. He appears. He
> vanishes. He goes unimpeded through walls, ramparts, and mountains as
> if through space. He dives in and out of the earth as if it were
> water. He walks on water without sinking as if it were dry land.
> Sitting cross-legged he flies through the air like a winged bird. With
> his hand he touches and strokes even the sun and moon, so mighty and
> powerful. He exercises influence with his body even as far as the
> Brahma worlds. Just as a skilled potter or his assistant could craft
> from well-prepared clay whatever kind of pottery vessel he likes, or
> as a skilled ivory-carver or his assistant could craft from
> well-prepared ivory any kind of ivory-work he likes, or as a skilled
> goldsmith or his assistant could craft from well-prepared gold any
> kind of gold article he likes; in the same way — with his mind thus
> concentrated, purified, and bright, unblemished, free from defects,
> pliant, malleable, steady, and attained to imperturbability — the monk
> directs and inclines it to the modes of supranormal powers... He
> exercises influence with his body even as far as the Brahma worlds."

The term used here is translated as "Mind-Made Body" (S. manomaya-kāya, C. yisheng shen 意生身). This text also details supernatural features, such as clairaudience and mind reading. Manomaya-kāya appears in various contexts in the Pali canon, which provide it with different shades of meaning. These are divided into three categories with nine subcategories:

1. Buddhist practice and attainment,

   - the body as part of a path of practice by practitioners bound for arhatship,
   - the body as the post-mortem destiny of disciples who achieve a certain level of attainment,
   - the body in which the Buddha visits the heaven of
     Brahmā,
   - the form in which the Buddha comes to a disciple to teach him (once),
   - the kind of body of a generous lay person reborn in a certain heaven.
2. cosmology,

   - the form in which certain devas are incarnated in some heavens
   - the form in which certain beings are reincarnated in the early part of a kalpa in various cosmogonic accounts
3. views of other schools

   - one of a range of objects of identification that can be mistaken for a permanent self, in a teaching where the Buddha refutes the notion of such a self,
   - part of one of seven nihilist views refuted by the Buddha in the
     Brahmajāla Sutta

In Mahayana texts, the term manomaya-kāya is frequently associated with the dharmakāya (Sanskrit: धर्म काय, "truth body" or "reality body", Chinese: 法身; pinyin: Fǎshēn, Tibetan: ཆོས་སྐུ་, Wylie: chos sku, rdzogs sku). This is one of the three bodies (trikāya) of a Buddha in Mahāyāna Buddhism. The dharmakāya constitutes the unmanifested, "inconceivable" (acintya) aspect of a buddha out of which buddhas arise and to which they return after their dissolution. Buddhas are manifestations of the dharmakāya called the nirmāṇakāya, "transformation body"

Note that this is only a short summary to answer your question for textual references that *could be* interpreted as OBE. These texts are not taken literally by the majority of Buddhist schools. For an in-depth scholarly analysis of the term, I recommend the following studies:

[The Meaning of ‘Mind-made Body’ in Buddhist Cosmological and Soteriological systems](https://journals.equinoxpub.com/BSR/article/view/20303/pdf)

[Early Buddhist Dhammakāya: Its Philosophical and Soteriological Significance](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/41232416.pdf)